# Load html on an element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I am trying to fill the html of a component with the result of an AJAX request, and it works... but only first time. This is for a phonegap application, and it tries to "encapsulate" a web on the app. I show you my code and after I´ll explain better.

## My code is this:

```
function loadPage(rute, callback) 
{
    console.log("ruta: " + rute);
    jQuery.get(rute, function(htmlTemplate) 
    {
        var data = eraseExtraContentExternalPages(jQuery(htmlTemplate).filter("#wrapper"));
        data     = eraseLinksExternalPages(data);
        console.log("#############BODY(wrapper)############# " + data.html());
        jQuery('body').html(data.html());
    });
}
function eraseExtraContentExternalPages(data)
{
    data.find('#secondary').remove();
    data.find('#dd_ajax_float').remove();
    data.find('#author-bio-box').remove();
    data.find('.googlepublisherpluginad').each(function(index){jQuery(this).remove();});
    return data;
}
function eraseLinksExternalPages(data)
{
    data.find("a").each(function(index)
    {
        var a    = jQuery(this);
        var href = a.attr("href");
        if(href && href.indexOf(".jpg")==-1 && href.indexOf(".gif")==-1 && href.indexOf(".png")==-1 && href.indexOf(".jpge")==-1)
            a.attr("href","javascript:loadPage('"+ href +"');"); 
    });
    return data;
}
```

What I do (I think is simple), I am trying to erease many html elements that are annoying on the app, and after change the href attribute of the "a" element, for a javascript action (loadPage), and it seems that works, becouse on the first console.log of the loadPage function I can see (when I press a link) how the rute is the correct, and on the second console.log I can see ALL THE CONTENT of data.html on the logcat (with eclipse), but the screen stay white-gray and with a little square on the left top corner...

Any Idea?? Why the html that I can see on the logs doesn´t load on the body??

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Why are you setting `data` twice? You're not doing anything with the first value of `data`.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()` to remove all the `.googlepublisherpluginad` elements. One call to `.remove()` will do them all.

Comment: Hello @Barmar. Thanks for the answer.
About the second coment... Yes, I deleted it, this is a old version (but the only different with the new is just this). 
About the data... I don´t understand at all. I am using data to pass it as argument to the other functions eraseLinksExternalPages, and Query('body').html(data.html()); but how I say, the second console.log shows all the data.html() correctly.

Comment: Oh, I missed that `data` was the argument to the second call.

Comment: What do you see if you examine the DOM in the DevTools?

Comment: What DevTools?? 
I am using phonegap and I use eclipse to see logsCat, and there I can see that the rute is correct and this: console.log("#############BODY(wrapper)############# " + data.html()); shows exactly the html from the web... everything seems correct, and the first time (when I launch the app) works fine...

Comment: I'm not familiar with PhoneGap, but I assume that when you're developing an application you use an environment that provides some kind of a Javascript debugger. Since PhoneGap allows you to develop the application using standard web technologies, you should be able to use a normal browser to debug it.

Comment: Hello @Barmar. I only know ripple, but I never had been enable to make it run with a litle big project (any way... I will try and tell you). I use eclipse, I run the app via CLI, but all the javascript errors or the console.log are shown on the logCat screen, and there is no javascript error, and the data.html before insert on the body is correct.